# How to make an array of colors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity

i made an application in processing, and now im trying to make an android application out of it. In processing i made an array of Colors.

```
color[] timeColours = {
color(246,230,196),
color(200,237,253),
color(252,199,202),
color(179,233,216),
color(247,233,174),
color(211,211,246),
color(108,59,57),
color(75,132,138),
color(124,96,66),
color(247,173,89),
color(235,108,63),
color(208,75,52),
color(255,202,39),
color(147,37,166),
color(22,158,250),
color(118,7,47),
color(44,183,80),
color(100,22,151),
color(88,42,71),
color(27,40,121),
color(29,112,74),
color(252,216,82),
color(247,99,64),
color(232,57,52)
};
```

and now i am trying to do the same in android. Any idea of how to do this?

thank you
Yop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
int[] colors = {Color.rgb(255,255,255), Color.rgb(255,242,0)};
myLabel.setTextColor(colors[1]);
```

Of course this can be accomplished by a lot of ways, this is just the solution that came to mind.